# File Path short cut

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this method, I saved an excel file in a directory in that path, instead of writing the whole path, is there a way to make it short so it automatically saves in the debug file?

```
using (var file = File.Open("C:\\Users\\john\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\EXCEl PROJECT\\webform\\" + filename + ".xlsx",FileMode.Create))
            {

                ms.WriteTo(file); // copy the memory stream to the file stream


            }
```

Comment: Take  a look in to [MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this property as your base directory. You may append to it as needed. 
`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Sample:

```
    using (var file = File.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\webform\\" + filename + ".xlsx", FileMode.Create))
    {
        ms.WriteTo(file); // copy the memory stream to the file stream
    }
```